# How do i omit the Confirm Form Resubmission from a backend point when user are logged in

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure, acs

I have this issue, its abit hard for me to explain but I hope it makes sense.

The issue is, I am using MVC 4 Asp.Net and authenticating using claims with Azure ACS, when the user logs in. A redirect to

1. ACS is initiated
2. ACS Posts data back to the server
3. The page is loaded (the network tool shows its a POST method)

Now if the user refresh the page the popup asks Confirm Form Resubmission. I assume this is because the site is a POST, so it think it should resend the stuff.

Are there anyway to change such its a normal GET instead of a POST that the user gets when it returns from ACS?

I hope my problem makes sense, I am not sure what to search for to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Yes, but i need some more specific, on how to hook this up in a MVC 4 Project. Im not sure where i would need to add this.

Comment: Depends on how your actions are set up. Just do a redirect in the controller action that handles the `POST` to the action that can handle a `GET`.

Comment: Its not a controller i have made. Actually its just a javascript windows.location = windows azure login url. That do a reply back to my server as a post. Its build into the WSFederationAuthenticationModule i guess.